# how to adjust width of columns to equal instead of grid system applied while using Twitter Bootstrap template.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've Twitter's bootstrap template, trying to justify (width) dynamic columns (number of columns varies from 3-12). For example how a 5 columns page equally spreads out in 12 grid system with utilizing whole screen width from edge to edge.

```
<?php
    $num_col = 5; // this value varies (fetched from database) as per user selection
    ?>

    <div class="row"><br />

    <?php
    //Running a for loop to generate coloumns.
    for($i = 0; $i<$num_col; $i++){
    ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <section class="panel">
              <div class="panel-body">Dynamic Text</div>
          </section>
      </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

For example a Bootstrap class added (.col-lg-3) to div tag to span whole page from left to right making 4 columns. The fifth column is sitting below the 1st column. If I'm using (.col-lg-2) for this, I'm utilizing only 10 grids out of 12.

I would like to know if there are 3 columns or 12 columns, the possible way to dynamically adjust on the screen with equal width.

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-lg-3 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-lg-3 {
    float: left;
  }

.col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap relies on 12 column grid and equally distributing 5 columns would need you to change the grid structure (by changing the less files). Put in 3 - 12 ranges and you will mostly end up with a large number of base columns.

An easier way would be to set the width inline on the element using style and calculate the width to put in (e.g. 5 columns = 100% / 5 = 20%, etc.)

Or you could define your own custom classes and add them after the bootstrap css. Note that you have to also account for the padding and other styles that bootstrap adds. An easy way to do this would be to just use the bootstrap column classes in addition to your column classes.

```
<div class="col-xs-1 my-by-5"></div>
```

with CSS

```
.my-by-5 {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qdv7xedh/

Comment: Yet to apply your code, but your code looks promising exactly what I was looking for. I'll post my updated comment later (especially after testing existing style, padding etc.)thanks